# Redirect after form success

Tags: php, redirect

pastebin of the php script:

http://pastebin.com/b43cZjLQ

```
// Form success
        // Remove the form element form the dom
        if($form_success){

            // Hide the form
            $form = $dom->getElementsByTagName('form')->item(0); 
            $form->setAttribute("style", "display: none");

            // Callbacks
            foreach($this->_callbacks as $data){
                if(is_callable($data['callback'])){
                    $result = call_user_func($data['callback'], $_POST, $data['config']);
                    $hide_id = $result ? self::ERROR_MESSAGE_ID : self::SUCCESS_MESSAGE_ID;
                    $this->hideIdElement($dom, $hide_id);   
                }else{
                    trigger_error( "Form handler is not callable", E_USER_ERROR);
                }
            }

        }

    }else{
        $this->hideIdElement($dom, self::SUCCESS_MESSAGE_ID);
        $this->hideIdElement($dom, self::ERROR_MESSAGE_ID);     
    }

    return str_replace(array(   '<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>', 
                                '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">',
                                '<html><body>', 
                                '</body></html>'), '',$dom->saveHTML());

}
```

What I'd like to do with this script is redirect to page (success.html)on success of form submission.

I am pretty new to PHP and would appreciate any help you could offer.

Thank you for taking the time to look at this, it's greatly appreciated.

EDIT: LOL Sorry for the first GIANT CODE DUMP! Fixed.

Comment: holy lol that's alot of code...!  For redirect use `header()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Hire a professional to do the job, if you're just gonna dump a lot of code and have us figure it out. I mean, if you knew a little bit about the subject, you'd probably have narrowed the code down to the significant parts.

Comment: Sorry about the code dump, totally wasn't paying attention to what I selected haha. Fixed it up and pasted the good parts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a redirect in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if( !empty( $_POST ) ) {
    header( "Location: success.html" ) ; exit ;
}
```

And yeah, it's a bit too much code to read, just show the part where your post action is directed to

Comment: Updated the code to reflect the success area. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using the function `header`, you can redirect the user to any other page.

Example:

```
header('location:success.html');
die();
```

Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

A common "gotchya" with `header` - be sure that no other portion of your script has had any output.  Any `echo` or `print` statement, or any error output (notices, warnings, etc) can cause your `header` statement to fail.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I'm having trouble finding where I should put that code. Any chance you could point me in the right direction? I am trying to learn by doing this but some times I need a helping hand.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<script>location.href='success.html';</script>";
```

:)